# How do you determine the area of a subsection of a circle?

Tags: geometry

How do you find the area of the highlighted subsection of a circle? Linked Below.

[image: Circle Problem]

The circle has a known radius from A-O and a trapezoid that lays inside it. The trapezoids longest edges contact the circle circumference at points D and E. All edge lengths of the trapezoid are known. The shortest distance from the center of the circle to the inner most edge of the trapezoid is also known, O-F.

I'm trying to design a lid with these dimensions and need to know the area to get the lids weight. The trapezoid portion with the highlighted area will float on top of a fluid. Unfortunately, I don't remember much from my High School geometry class.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: is it  ,$BCDE$, parallelogram or trapezium?

Answer (score 1):

Since $OF $ is the shortest distance, OFB and OFC are right angles. Let G be the intersection of $OA$ and $ED$. Since $BC$ is parallel to $ED$, $OGE$ and $OGD$ are right triangles. By the Hypotenuse Leg rule for congruent triangles, $EG$=$GD$.

So the area of the sector is :

$A=(R^2/2)\theta - (1/4) R^2 \sin\theta$

Where $2R\sin (\theta/2)=ED$